# How to run a PHP function 1 minute from now?

Tags: php, mysql, time

I have `MySQL` service on Windows Server. I have a script in `PHP`, when the user runs it, it should stop the `MySQL` service, and then after 60 seconds it must start the service again. I wrote some code like this:

```
$stopTime = time();
$now = date("H:i", time());
$mustRun = date("H:i", intval($stopTime)+60);

while(trim(strval($now)) !== trim(strval($mustRun))) {
    continue;
} // now it should be start mysql service
```

I saved the running time in the `$stopTime` variable, and calculated the 60 seconds after using `$mustRun` variable.
I want to start the service when the current time is `$mustRun`, How can I do that?

Comment: Why would you want this? And PHP is not the best tool for it. Use a task scheduler.

Comment: I should write it using PHP. It is the request of department manager.

Comment: If you can use JavaScript approach, you can execute another PHP page/ script 60 seconds after you stop your MySQL service, using `setTimeout()`

Comment: just curious, what if the PHP script is executed by many users at the same time?

Comment: Apart from the fact that you want the script to sleep rather than use 100% CPU for a whole minute (see the answers you have so far) I suggest you take some time to learn how date functions work. You do really weird stuff like applying `intval()` to a int, applying `strval()` to a string or converting dates to strings before comparing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can try php's [sleep](https://www.php.net/sleep).

```
<?php

// sleep for 60 seconds
sleep(60);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use 'sleep' in combination with **outputbuffering**.
Something like:

```
<?php
ob_start();
$buffer = str_repeat(" ", 4096);

for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
  echo $buffer.$i;
  ob_flush();
  flush();
  sleep(60);
}
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Without using **outputbuttering**, 'sleep' won't show the behaviour as expected.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use cronjob in your server

This method is more reliable because in some cases it may be due to the security settings of webserver ,your code do not correct work

look at this link

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this function that use a callback called after specified time

> ```
> function delay_exec($function_name,$param,$delay) {
>     $ret = null;
>     if (!is_int($delay) || !is_function($function_name)) {
>         echo "<h2>Errore </h2>"
>         return $ret;
>     }
>     sleep($delay);
>     $ret = call_user_func_array($function_name,$param);
>     return $ret;
> }
> ```

So if u have `foo($a,$b)` to call, you can call like this way:

> delay_exec('foo',array($a,$b),60);

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'sleep()' or 'usleep()' method instead of a while loop, pass in the amount of time you want to pause.